# I don't know how to avoid resubstitution on clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to write something like this when expressed in python.

```
a = int(input())
for i in range(a):
    b = input()
    print(b)
```

And this is what I actually wrote.

```
(let [a][(read-line)]
     (for[i (range [a])]
            (defn b[string]
                (= (read-line) b)
                 (println [b]))))
```

But now there are many errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the Python flow.

```
(doseq [_ (range (Integer. (read-line)))
    :let [b (read-line)]]
    (println b))
```

Even closer to Python code:

```
(let [a (Integer. (read-line))]
  (doseq [i (range a)
      :let [b (read-line)]]
          (println b)))
```

More functional Code

```
(mapv println (repeatedly (Integer. (read-line)) read-line))
```

But more idiomatic (per  Sean Corfield)

```
(run! println (repeatedly (Integer. (read-line)) read-line))
```

Comment: Since you are "mapping" over a collection purely for side-effects (the println call), it's more idiomatic to use run! instead of map/mapv.

Comment: Thanks, @SeanCorfield--updated my response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could do something like:

`(map (fn [_] (println (read-line))) (range (Integer/parseInt (read-line))))`

There may be something more appropriate than a map here, read the clojure documentation.  The clojure standard library has a lot of cool stuff :)

Edit: @SeanCorfield brought up a good point in the comments, using [run!](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!)  would be a better choice here since we don't care about the return value of map.

Comment: run! would be more appropriate/idiomatic than map here (since this is all about side-effects).

Answer (score 0):

or this...

```clj
(repeatedly
 (read-string (read-line))
 (comp println read-line))
```